# File Details on a Windows like folder pane

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to show file details in a GridView for my web application. Also I need to list them in uploaded date order with most recent on top (descending order). For example I need the following details.

```
FileName | Extension | UploadedDate | LastDownloadedDate
```

I couldn't find any code on the web. Sorry, this could be easy but I only know how to get the files into a strying array. Here I get only filenames

```
String[] files = Directory.GetFiles("myPath");
```

How do I get the rest of the details?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.IO.FileInfo` class to get a `List` and then bind it to the `GridView`.

```
System.IO.FileInfo[] fInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("YOUR_PATH").GetFiles();

var filList = (from f in fInfo
           orderby f.CreationTime descending 
           select new
           {
             FileName = f.Name,
             UploadedDate = f.CreationTime,
             Extension = f.Extension,
             LastDownloadedDate = f.LastAccessTime //Not sure this would be the same.
           }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look to the `System.IO` namespace:

```
string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(this.File1.PostedFile.FileName);
string path= Path.GetFileName(fileName);
string LastModified=System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(Server.MapPath("myFile.txt")).ToString();
```

Comment: This gives only one file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861886/how-to-get-file-properties) might help you, but i am not sure if you can get any uploaded / downloaded information in any default propreties.

You can set some custom / extended properties to save those information and read the same when displaying on grid. Read and writing extended property depends on the file extension.