# How to read file properties from many different files and save them to Excel

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, batch-file, file-properties

First, thanks for trying to answer my question.

Ok, so I have loads of files (somewhere in the excess of about 500) from which I need to grab some of their properties. I need the File Name, Date Created, and Author and I'd like them to be saved into an Excel sheet.

Any idea on how I'd go about doing this? I've got a little bit of C# and VB.Net programming skills but not a lot. Anything you can do to help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get file properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861886/how-to-get-file-properties)

Comment: What have you tried? There are enough tools for working with file system and Excel in `.NET`

Comment: This question probably answers your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536636/write-array-to-excel-range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get a way of parsing through all the files (e.g. Loop through the return result of [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx))
2. create a [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileInfo.aspx) object for each file, and then check [`properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_properties.aspx) you are looking for.
3. find an API to create the Excel file (e.g [`Excel interop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) to create an Excel and insert your information of each file into a row.