# how do you get File Listing Details on c#

Tags: c#, file, directory-listing

i'm currently doing an assignment at university and i'm struggling on a specific task

After displaying a file listing i need to prompt the user to enter the number of a file to get more details on that file. The user can then enter the number 0 to skip this step. The extra details shown should be:

```
File: notepad.exe
Full file name: C:\Windows\notepad.exe
File size: 93536 bytes
Created: 14/07/2009 12:54:24
Last accessed: 10/08/2009 15:21:05
```

im using C# im wondering if anyone knows how to guide me on the right step? thankyou

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7861886/945456

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For general file information, like size and creation and modification times, use the [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"C:\Windows\Notepad.exe");
long size = f.Length;
DateTime creation = f.CreationTime;
DateTime modification = f.LastWriteTime;
string name = f.Name; //returns "Notepad.exe"
//etc...
```

Alternatively, for getting a filename from a full path, use the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
string fName = Path.GetFilename(@"C:\Windows\Notepad.exe"); //returns "Notepad.exe"
```

I'll leave formatting the info string to you.

Be advised that `FileInfo` depends on the existence of the file, while the `Path` methods only deal with string manipulation. The file does not need to exist.