# how to find filename with the help of time creation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

I have a date and time when file was created in a system and I am trying to get the filename with the help of date and time.
It is possible or not, if it is possible then anyone please tell me. How can I get a filename using data and time in c#.

**Note: Date and time means when file was created in a system.**

Comment: you can use FileInfo.CreationTime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861886/how-to-get-file-properties

Comment: what did you try yourself? Where specifically do you need help? Where is your code?

Comment: You can do that by combining the answers to these three questions:

[Getting a list of logical drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781905/getting-a-list-of-logical-drives), 
[How to recursively list all the files in a directory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c) and [How to get File Created Date and Modified Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243336/). Or if you already know the drive or a part of the path, you can skip directly to the second one. Where exactly are you stuck?